# Invalid TTY after SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, tty

I changed display managers recently on my linux install (from slim to console tdm). And, ever since that (note: I probably was doing other things at the time as well, so I can't be certain it was the change in display managers), when I ssh into my machine, I get the following message:

```
Invalid tty
```

After the message, I am given a prompt and everything works as normal. But, it just seems strange. Anyone know what this means?

Comment: It's unlikely the display manager affects tty stuff. Where does the message come from? Executing something in `.profile` / `.bashrc` etc. (comment things out and see if the message disappears)? From `ssh` itself? What does `tty` say?

Comment: So, in the directions for installing console TDM (my new display manager), I am told to put the line `source /usr/bin/tdm` in my `.bash_profile`. I commented this line out, and the `Invalid tty` warning goes away. Since I need that line in my `.bash_profile`, I guess I'm stuck with the warning?

Comment: I'm not familiar with tdm. Looking at the [git](https://github.com/dopsi/console-tdm/blob/master/tdm), it's a bash file, so the next step should be debugging this to see where the message comes from. Or conctact the author on github and see if he has any ideas what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

This is, in fact, tdm's error reporting left unchecked. If you change the entry at the end of .xinitrc to read

```
exec tdm --xstart --silent
```

all *should* be well, however, there appears to be a bug, and --silent isn't acted upon. My solution was to edit the tdm executable script directly - at the beginning where variables are set, I changed

```
silent=true
```

to false.